# How can I retrieve screen unlock times in gnome?

Tags: linux, redhat, gnome

The `last` command only retrieves the login times. I'm interested in the times that the screen was unlocked. Any indirect means of getting this are also welcome.

Comment: What do you want this for?

Comment: @vonbrand it is useful to know the time we spend on a computer every day, I found this question because of this.

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the system logs? You should see an authentication message in `/var/log/secure` when someone attempts to unlock the screen.

For instance, when using KDE and someone types in the wrong password:

```
Mar  7 14:19:05 saurok kcheckpass[16479]: pam_sss(kscreensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname=username uid=248800001 euid=248800001 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= user=username
```

And a successful unlock:

```
Mar  7 14:19:09 saurok kcheckpass[16483]: pam_sss(kscreensaver:auth): authentication success; logname=username uid=248800001 euid=248800001 tty=:0 ruser= rhost= user=username
```

Yours will vary slightly (this machine is on a domain) but it should be present.

Comment: While I didn't find a kcheckpass log entry, I did grep through and find a log entry in /var/log/gdm/0.log and in /var/log/Xorg.0.log with the first entry of the day being a 'client connected from local host'. That seems to be an indication of my first login of the day, however it's not a solid "authenticated" exactly.

Comment: Neither of those are `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: Correct. It appears `/var/log/secure` doesn't have any entries for known screen unlock times. May not be an equivalent to kcheckpass on gnome.

Comment: How strange. If your system is using PAM for authentication, then you should be getting log entries regardless of what's being used.